# Upload Image from Expo to NestJS Server as Binary

Tags: file-upload, expo, nestjs, expo-file-system, expo-image-picker

I have an Expo Client trying to upload images from iOS and Android to a NestJS Server.

I get a 400 error that `File is required`, and when I try to log the body on the server it's empty.

My client code is

```
        try {
          const token = await getItemAsync(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
          const res = await FileSystem.uploadAsync(
            `${FULL_URL}`,
            media.assets[0].uri,
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              },
              fieldName: 'photo',
            }
          );
          console.log(res);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("ERROR")
          console.log(error);
        }
```

And my Server on the receiving end is

```
    @Post()
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('photo'))
    public async createGalleryImages(
        @Req() { userId },
        @UploadedFile(new ParseFilePipe({
            validators: [new FileTypeValidator({
                fileType: 'image'
            })]
        })) file: Express.Multer.File) {
        try {
            console.log(file)
          
            return Builder<CreateGalleryImageResponse>()
                .build();
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error("Error creating gallery images", error, { galleryId });
        }
    }
```

Why isn't the expo-file-system `uploadAsync` sending the binary data from the file URI? I'd prefer not to use Base64 since that format would be transmitting more data than is necessary.

Any help is greatly appreciated!